# Running the 64 bit TeamSpeak 3 server

Tags: raspbian, server, 64-bit

I am using the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (64 bit) and I'd like to run a TeamSpeak 3 server on it. Since there is a [64 bit version](http://teamspeak.com/downloads#server) available , it shouldn't be a problem, right?

The server even seems to start, as suggested by this message (if you ignore the second line):

```
Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
./ts3server: 1: ./ts3server: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file
```

After this, nothing else is output. The problem is I'm unable to find the log file anywhere and `ps x` tells me the server is not even running...
I should probably note that I get a different output trying to start the server from the root user:

```
Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
./ts3server: 1: ./ts3server: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
TeamSpeak 3 server could not start
```

Can someone explain what is happening here (and maybe how to fix it)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) is more than just an instruction/address size.  ARMv8, aka. aarch64, is not the same as x86-64, which is what the TeamSpeak binaries will be for (tangential to this, the system libraries on almost all Pi distros are 32-bit anyway, with which the Pi 3 is backward compatible, but it means you will not be able to run dynamically linked 64-bit binaries).

The fact that it seems to start is simply indicative of the fact that a start-up script is used.

I had a peek in the linux download from the page you linked.

```
> file ts3server 
ts3server: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
                                      ^^^^^^
```

That's no good.  The script the error is being thrown from is `ts3server_startscript.sh`.

```sh
echo "Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server"
if [ -e "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
        if [ ! -x "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
                echo "${BINARYNAME} is not executable, trying to set it"
                chmod u+x "${BINARYNAME}"
        fi
        if [ -x "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
                export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LIBRARYPATH}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"                                      
                "./${BINARYNAME}" ${COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} > /dev/null &
                PID=$!
                ps -p ${PID} > /dev/null 2>&1
                if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
                        echo "TeamSpeak 3 server could not start"
                else
                        echo $PID > ts3server.pid
                        echo "TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file"
                fi
        else
                echo "${BINARNAME} is not exectuable, cannot start TeamSpeak 3 server"
        fi
```

Note the fail being caught. If you try to run that directly on a pi, you will probably get:

```
Failed to execute process './ts3server'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file './ts3server' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still wondering where the output `./ts3server: 1: ./ts3server: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` is coming from, because the startup script does not contain anything like this?