# Run blender 2.8 headless on pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, headless

I am trying to run blender 2.8 headless on raspberry pi 3b+ running raspbian. I have downloaded the Linux version from the blender website. But whenever I open the executable called “blender” in terminal, a window appears for a split second and the disappears. Also, after executing, a new empty text file appears in the folder with a crazy name (shown below). I am wondering what I am doing wrong and if it is possible.

[image: the executable file is selected]

[image: i’ve tried both execute and execute in terminal]

[image: the crazy named text file]

I have tried installing blender in the following way:
    
`sudo apt-get install blender`

But this just gives me the 2.79 version. I have heard that pi doesn’t support the version of OpenGL used in blender 2.8, but I also heard that if you use 2.8 headless, it doesn’t require OpenGL. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you described very clearly what you observed, but you did not say anything about any problems

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || Which RPi model? Which OS? Add output of `apt install blender`. Might work.

Comment: What Raspbian version do you use? Do you use Raspbian Buster? Please use a tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running the 64 bit TeamSpeak 3 server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59341/running-the-64-bit-teamspeak-3-server)

Comment: From the terminal, run `blender`. If there's any error messages, it should show you in the terminal. To open a terminal, open the folder with the file browser and hit `F4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the folder name I see that you got an `x86_64` version of the software, and it's very unlikely that you got it using `sudo apt-get install blender`. All Raspberries have an ARM CPU and cannot run x86 code without an emulator (and this is most probably **not** what you want). Get an `armhf` version of the software.

If you wonder how that strange file came into existence: if you try to execute a file those format is not recognized, the system will try to run it as a shell script, and if that file contains a string `>blabla` terminated by a newline, it will be interpreted as an output redirection by the shell, which will create a file named `blabla`.