# Installing STM32CubeProgrammer on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation

I need to install STM32CubeProgrammer on Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Server (no desktop). Anyone succeeded with such a setup? To begin with, the installation instructions require the installation of OpenJFX which is not relevant (nor possible, in lieu of X) in this case, I intend to use only the CLI interface. Trying to run the installation script after failing the installation of OpenJFX results with the following:

```
user@host:~ $ sudo ./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.3.0.linux 
[sudo] password for user: 
./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.3.0.linux: 1: ./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.3.0.linux: ELFJ�4��: not found
./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.3.0.linux: 2: ./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.3.0.linux: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

EDIT: As @Goldilocks noted its seems that the install script is for x86; still looking for a way to install on RPI.

Comment: You should probably explain where you got this since there are a few things which would indicate it *cannot* be run on a Pi.  Are you aware of the significance of the [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) (x86 vs. ARM, etc)?  Edit in the output of `file ./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.3.0.linux `.

Comment: @goldilocks Got this on the RPI command line; "there are a few things which would indicate it cannot be run on a Pi" - but is there a definite idea whether it can or cannot?

Comment: I meant, where you got the software from.  If you wait around for someone who's actually experienced using it, you may be waiting a long time.  However, there are ways to determine if it *cannot* be used that don't require familiarity.  The output of `file` is one thing that would indicate this.  It has to do with the ISA...

Comment: @goldilocks Well I got the software from the ST official download page, and the setup file is the original binary executable

Comment: So the answer to the question I asked earlier, *"Are you aware of the significance of the ISA?"* would be **"No"**.   Your problem is probably more or less this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59342/5538

Comment: *"still looking for a way to install on RPI"* -> It's not just the install script.  If that is proprietary software for which the source is not publically available, the only thing you can install are precompiled binaries.  Unless there is a version of them for ARMv6, you are out of luck (ARMv7 might be okay on models compatible with that, but you won't be able to do it with Raspbian).  ST doesn't seem to have a download page accessible without an account, but if they have this the choice would be pretty obvious.

Comment: The problem seems to be essentially the same as [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107730/run-blender-2-8-headless-on-pi): x86 executable failing to run on ARM hardware.